# How to call presentModalViewController from ParentViewController Method in paging app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parent-child, presentmodalviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I'm using a Page App. I have a viewController A and this have a scrollView with 3 others viewController lets call them ViewController B,C,D and I switch controllers B,C,D using scroller's paging. My problem is: I want to call presentModalViewController from a button in ViewController B but when I do this in ViewControllerB.m

```
-(void) nextController{
    ViewControllerE *controllerE = [[[ViewControllerE alloc] init]autorelease];
    controllerE.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controllerE animated:YES];
}
```

It works and cover only B's view but I still can switch between E,C,D. I don't want this. I want to call this method from parent ViewController A, because when I call ViewController E, I want to make paging off.

I tried:

```
   [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:controllerE animated:YES];
```

But didn't work.

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1):

What's the result of this:

```
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:controllerE animated:YES];
```

Does it give you an error - does anything happen?

Try debugging with this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController);
```

what result does it give you?